# Create object using Underscore.js

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

What is the correct Underscore.js way to create a new object called items that consists of each of the item arrays. Where I could then make a POST of each item.name in one call?

```
var items = [];

item = [{
  name: "item1",
  desc: "this is a description of item 1",
  qty: 1
},{
  name: "item2",
  desc: "this is a description of item 2",
  qty: 5
},{
  name: "item3",
  desc: "this is a description of item 3",
  qty: 3
}];

items.push(item);
```

Comment: The item arrays are invalid. You need to use the `{ ... }` object syntax instead (i.e. `item = { name: "item1", desc: "this is... }`. If you're going to create the objects this way, you'll also want to call `items.push(item);` after each object literal. Otherwise you're never going to have anything in your array as `item` has not been defined at the time of reference.

Comment: Thanks, updated but not my question.

Comment: Sorry, but the question doesn't really make sense. Those aren't item arrays. They're objects. Typically, you'll create an array `items` that contains the `item` objects. If you want `items` to be an object and each `item` to be an object, you'll need to determine what the names of the three subobjects will be.

Comment: Okay I understand maybe I have phrased it in the wrong way.  I want access the object item and via dot notation each item's say name. It's okay if it's item1, item2 and item3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to convert an array of items to an object where each key is the name of the object

e.g.

```
{
    item1: {
         name: "item1",
         desc: "this is a description of item 1",
         qty: 1
    },
    item2: { ... },
    item3: { ... },
}
```

If that's the case then you could use the [**object**](http://underscorejs.org/#object) function that takes two parameters; the first being the list of property names and the second a list of the values:

```
    var items = [{
          name: "item1",
          desc: "this is a description of item 1",
          qty: 1
        },{
          name: "item2",
          desc: "this is a description of item 2",
          qty: 5
        },{
          name: "item3",
          desc: "this is a description of item 3",
          qty: 3
        }
    ];

    var itemsAsAnObject = _.object( _.pluck(items,'name'), items)
```